# Parse custom Objects with string input

Tags: java, parsing, reflection, overriding

I want to parse objects where I have an input value. The object has subclasses.

I don't want to create an instance when I want to parse the string.
But I want to override the method 'parse'.

```
class A {
  public A(object param) {
   //code
  }
  public A parse(String input) {
   //code
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public B parse(String input) {
   //code
  }
}
```

And when I parse the objects I want do it with reflection:

```
A newObject =  Class.forName(className).getMethod("parse", myParseText);
```

Is there a nice way to do that.

Comment: If the method is not static, there is no way to do that without creating an instance. What is your *real* problem? Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I want to override the parse method. But it should be static. Or should I use a constructor. But then there is no override annotation.
And my problem is that I want have one method that can use with reflection that parse a string to my object.

Comment: But why do you want to do this with reflection rather than just calling the method?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I want to do this with reflection, because the code which call the method first finds out which type the object has and then it should parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For maximum flexibility I'd move the parsing code out into a separate parser class. The following code is for example a simplified implementation of a parser class I am using in a project myself:

```
public final class ParseUtil {

    public interface IStringParser<E> {
        public E parse(String s) throws ParseException;
    }

    private ParseUtil() {}

    private static Map<Class<?>, IStringParser<?>> STRING_PARSERS = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static <E> void registerStringParser(Class<E> c, IStringParser<E> p){
        STRING_PARSERS.put(c, p);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <E> IStringParser<E> getStringParser(Class<E> c){
        return (IStringParser<E>) STRING_PARSERS.get(c);
    }

    public static <E> E parse(String s, Class<E> clazz) throws ParseException{
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0 || clazz == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        IStringParser<E> stringParser = getStringParser(clazz);
        if (stringParser == null) {
            throw new ParseException(clazz);
        }
        return stringParser.parse(s);
    }
}
```

One can then register `IStringParser` implementations for arbitrary classes to the `ParserUtil` like so:

```
ParseUtil.registerStringParser(File.class, new IStringParser<File>() {
    @Override
    public File parse(String s)throws ParseException {
        return new File(s);
    }
});
```

Or using a lambda: `ParseUtil.registerStringParser(File.class, s -> new File(s));`

It is the responsibility of the caller to decide how to parse a class and when the `IStringParser` is registered/unregistered.

By moving the parsing code away from the class itself, it is easy to change the implementation later simply by registering a different `IStringParser` or by changing the `parse` method of the `ParseUtil` class. For example in my own project I use the following parse method that provides some reasonable defaults for well known Java classes and uses [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse Objects for which no other `IStringParser` is registered:

```
public static <E> E parse(String s, Class<E> clazz) throws ParseException{
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0 || clazz == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    IStringParser<E> stringParser = getStringParser(clazz);
    if (stringParser != null) {
        return stringParser.parse(s);
    }
    if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        // simple number
        try {
            if (clazz == Integer.class) {
                return clazz.cast(Integer.parseInt(s));
            }
            if (clazz == Long.class) {
                return clazz.cast(Long.parseLong(s));
            } 
            if (clazz == Double.class) {
                return clazz.cast(Double.parseDouble(s));
            } 
            if (clazz == Float.class) {
                return clazz.cast(Float.parseFloat(s));
            }
            if (clazz == Short.class) {
                return clazz.cast(Short.parseShort(s));
            }
            if (clazz == Byte.class) {
                return clazz.cast(Byte.parseByte(s));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ParseException(clazz, e);
        }
    } 
    if (clazz == String.class) {
        return clazz.cast(s);
    }
    if (clazz == Character.class) {
        if (s.length() == 1) {
            return clazz.cast(s.charAt(0));
        } else{
            throw new ParseException("Unable to parse Character \"" + s + "\"");
        }
    }
    if (clazz == Boolean.class) {
        switch (s) {
        case "true":
            return clazz.cast(Boolean.TRUE);
        case "false":
            return clazz.cast(Boolean.FALSE);
        case "1":
            return clazz.cast(Boolean.TRUE);
        case "0":
            return clazz.cast(Boolean.FALSE);
        default:
            throw new ParseException("Unable to parse boolean \"" + s + "\"");
        }
    }
    if (clazz == Class.class) {
        try {
            return clazz.cast(Class.forName(s));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ParseException(clazz, e);
        }
    }
    if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
        Class c = (Class)clazz;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Object o = Enum.valueOf(c, s);
        return clazz.cast(o);
    }
    E result = null;
    try {
        // if all else fails use Gson to parse the class
        result = getGSON().fromJson(s, clazz);
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        throw new ParseException(clazz. e);
    }

    if (result == null) {
        throw new ParseException(clazz);
    }
    return result;
}
```